# How to push Reactjs logs and metrics to Grafana

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, grafana, grafana-loki

**Background:**

I am working on a project where we have a server setup in Java and for front-end we are using ReactJs. Our server ships all logs to Loki endpoint via their push API and all metrics to a prometheus push-gateway. Grafana then pulls those logs and metrics from Loki and push-gateway for display.

**Requirement:**

I want to **persist** and place the **ReactJs** application **logs and metrics** so they are visible on **grafana**. This will help us see both frontend and backend application logs & metrics in the same place. Is there a **free**, **opensource** Javascript library or framework that can help me with that. The less code I need to write the better.

I was opting for sentry before but it's not completely free anymore. And we cannot use console logging as it disappears on browser refresh and not really helpful in production

Comment: There's a Grafana blog entry about this kind of thing with some examples https://grafana.com/blog/2022/07/07/how-to-configure-grafana-loki-with-a-node.js-e-commerce-app/

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find a good library at that time but I was eventually able to ship logs to loki push endpoint.

I tried to push logs directly from frontend to loki push endpoint. This gave me a cors error. So I came up with the following steps to get around cors with Loki.

**My workaround:**

1. Setup nginx proxy server.
2. Nginx resolves cors.
3. Add reverse proxy to nginx. I send request to nginx host and then it forwards that request to loki from within same network so no cors.

I took alot of reading and hit and trys but I got the setup working. We are now using this setup to push frontend logs to grafana

Comment: Can you please provide nginx config for the same?